# Create json files from dataframe

Tags: python, json

I have a dataframe with 10 rows like this:

| id | name | team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Employee1 | Team1 |
| 2 | Employee2 | Team2 |
| ... |  |  |

How can I generate 10 json files from the dataframe with python?
Here is the format of each json file:

{

"Company": "Company",

"id": "1",

"name": "Employee1",

"team": "Team1"

}

- The field "Company": "Company" is the same in all json files.
- Name of each json file is the name of each employee (i.e Employee1.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really like `iterrows` but as you need a file per row, I cannot imagine how to vectorize the operation:

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Company'] = 'Company'
    row.to_json(row['name'] + '.json')
```

Comment: I think that it would better to set the company column to the entire data frame and not to each row. Like what I suggested to in my comment to my answer

Comment: @DavidS: adding a column will change the original Dataframe, while setting the field for each row will not. Only OP can know which one is better in their use case...

Comment: How can I put the id in double quote like this: "id": ''1''?

Comment: @Harper: You can convert everything to strings with `astype`: `... row.as-type(str).to_json(row['name'] + '.json')`

Comment: Last question: how can I separate each field into one line like in my example? Now everything is in one line only

Comment: It is explicit in the [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html?highlight=to_json#pandas.Series.to_json): `to_json(..., indent=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` in the following way:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
```

And inside the `to_json` pass the employee name, it’s available to you in `x`

Another approach is to iterate over the rows like:

```
for i in df.index:
    df.loc[i].to_json("Employee{}.json".format(i))
```

Comment: Hi how can I insert "Company": "Company" into the files?

Comment: @Harper just add a column to the data frame before. `df["Company"] = “Company”`